# How to exclude java.activation?

Tags: java, jaxb, maven-3, java-9, java-10

module-info.java in the various projects which comprise a working JAXB include:

```
    requires transitive jakarta.activation;
```

For example, https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/blob/master/jaxb-ri/runtime/impl/src/main/java/module-info.java#L23

But under Java 10, when installing my project which uses JAXB, maven complains:

```
[ERROR] module org.jvnet.staxex reads package javax.activation from both java.activation and jakarta.activation
[ERROR] module com.sun.xml.bind reads package javax.activation from both java.activation and jakarta.activation
[ERROR] the unnamed module reads package javax.activation from both jakarta.activation and java.activation
```

Since I can't see how to hide java.activation, I started re-compiling the various JAXB projects so they require java.activation instead of jakarta.activation

This works, but it can't be the correct solution!  How do I hide/exclude java.activation in Java 10? thanks.

Comment: If you change the scope of your JAXB dependencies to `<scope>runtime</scope>`, does it fix your problem?

Comment: if i change the scope of com.sun.xml.bind jaxb-impl to runtime, mvn says "module-info.java:[17,29] module not found: com.sun.xml.bind"

Comment: Do you really need this module? It is possible to avoid it?

Comment: For java 11, jaxb is using jakarta.activation and it works fine there, since there is no java.activation.  But it seems the jaxb guys might not have addressed using Java 10?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
--patch-module java.activation=jakarta.activation-<version>.jar
```

`jakarta.activation-<version>.jar` Should be the filename of the jar